# Tomcat 7 : Filtering lifecycle events

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have defined a LifecycleListener class and added it to the `<host>` configuration inside the server.xml as I am interested in few of the lifecycle events of the Tomcat server [and not the contexts]: before_Start,start,before_stop.

> ```
> > <Host name="localhost" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false"
> > deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">      .
> >                 <Listener className="com.sample.ServerLifecycleListener" />
> > 
> > </Host>
> ```

What I observe is, there are lot of events :periodic, etc for which my listener is getting invoked.

Is there a way to configure the LifecycleListener with only the list of events that I am interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to configure that. **The LifeCycleListener interface is very basic and does not accept any configuration, its entire implementation is provided by you.** You can however easily filter out the unwanted messagetypes within your listener. These are the types you may receive:

[Tomcat 7 lifecycle events](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.java#Lifecycle.0PERIODIC_EVENT)